# Oracle error: UDI-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 11.01.00.06.00

Tags: oracle, datapump

I'm trying to use data pump to move the database to a different server with this command:

```
impdp dbuser/dbpsw@dbserver directory=data_pump_dir network_link=sourceDB schemas=EMP
```

But I got this error:

> UDI-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version
>   11.01.00.06.00

The source DB version is:

> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - 64bit
>   Production      PL/SQL Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
>   CORE  11.1.0.6.0  Production
>   TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
>   NLSRTL Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production

The target DB version is:

> Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
>   PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
>   CORE  11.2.0.2.0  Production
>   TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
>   NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Does it mean I need to upgrade source DB version to be same as target DB?
If I can't upgrade database on the source DB, can I only upgrade the impdp utility? If yes, how?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: your target db is "dbserver". What is the version of your impdp utility. Are you starting impdp on the server were "dbserver" is running. Is it the impdp from the "dbserver" ORACLE_HOME?